# Laravel 4 redirects Slug

Tags: redirect, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

i have a route for a hotel view with a slug hotel name.

```
Route::get('/hotel/{slug}', function($slug){
    $id  = Hotel::whereSlug($slug)->firstOrFail()->id;
    $hotel = Hotel::find($id);
    return View::make('hotel')
    ->with('hotel', $hotel);
});
```

i have a RoomsController with postStore method()

```
   <?php

class RoomsController extends BaseController {

public function postStore(){
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), Room::$rules);
    if($validator->passes()){
        $room = new Room;
        $room->name = Input::get('name');
        $room->description = Input::get('description');
        $room->facilities = Input::get('facilities');
        $room->info = Input::get('info');
        $room->price = Input::get('price');
        $room->beds = Input::get('beds');
        $room->no_of_rooms = Input::get('no_of_rooms');
        $room->hotel_id = Input::get('hotel_id');
        $room->save();
        return Redirect::to('hotel/')
        ->with('success', 'Room successfully created!');
    }
    return Redirect::back()
    ->with('error', 'Something went wrong!')
    ->withErrors($validator)
    ->withInput();
  }
}
```

my doubt here is how to redirect to hotel view page(the previous route) after saving the rooms.

Comment: Please include the code where you call `postStore()`

Comment: @Rafael i didnt get you i have already posted the postStore in question

Comment: Where are you calling that function?

Comment: i have edited my question.....can you please help me now @Rafael

Comment: I really do want to help you but your still not showing me where you are calling postStore();  What I mean is in your route who is calling postStore method.  Is your method being called from a view using link_to_action?  Where are you CALLING this function / invoking , etc.

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is something you're not telling us, you have the hotel id, so just load the Hotel record, get the slug, and redirect to the url:

```
// ...
$room->save();
$hotel = Hotel::find(Input::get('hotel_id'));
return Redirect::to(URL::to('hotel', array($hotel->slug)))
    ->with('success', 'Room successfully created!');
// ...
```